# Aspose.Words - merge two documents at specific location

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

using ASPOSE.WORDS (.Net) i am trying to merge two RTF documents one within another.

I would like to have an entire document replace a string of text in the second document.

So far i've been able to concatenate two documents but that's not exactly what i'm after.

```
const string BOOKMARK = @"UNIQUE_STRING"; //UNUSED at the moment

Aspose.Words.Document dWords = new Aspose.Words.Document(@"C:\RTFM\test1.rtf", LoadFormat.Rtf,"");
Aspose.Words.Document dWords2 = new Aspose.Words.Document(@"C:\RTFM\test2.rtf", LoadFormat.Rtf, "");

ImportFormatMode mode = ImportFormatMode.KeepSourceFormatting;

foreach (Section srcSection in dWords2)
{
    Node dstSection = dWords.ImportNode(srcSection, true, mode);
    dWords.AppendChild(dstSection);
}

dWords.Save(@"C:\output.rtf")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you need to implement IReplacingCallback interface to find the text and replace it with a document(rtf). Use the following code example to achieve your requirements.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "input.rtf");

FindandInsertDocument replacedoc = new FindandInsertDocument(MyDir + "document to be inserted.rtf");

doc.Range.Replace(new Regex("text which needs to be replaced with document"), replacedoc, false); 

doc.Save(MyDir + "Out.rtf");
```

*FindandInsertDocument class:*

```
private class FindandInsertDocument : IReplacingCallback
{
    private String path;

    public FindandInsertDocument(String documentpath)
    {
        path = documentpath;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called by the Aspose.Words find and replace engine for each match.
    /// </summary>
    ReplaceAction IReplacingCallback.Replacing(ReplacingArgs e)
    {
        // This is a Run node that contains either the beginning or the complete match.
        Node currentNode = e.MatchNode;

        // The first (and may be the only) run can contain text before the match,
        // in this case it is necessary to split the run.
        if (e.MatchOffset > 0)
            currentNode = SplitRun((Run)currentNode, e.MatchOffset);

        // This array is used to store all nodes of the match for further removing.
        ArrayList runs = new ArrayList();

        // Find all runs that contain parts of the match string.
        int remainingLength = e.Match.Value.Length;
        while (
            (remainingLength > 0) &&
            (currentNode != null) &&
            (currentNode.GetText().Length <= remainingLength))
        {
            runs.Add(currentNode);
            remainingLength = remainingLength - currentNode.GetText().Length;

            // Select the next Run node.
            // Have to loop because there could be other nodes such as BookmarkStart etc.
            do
            {
                currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling;
            }
            while ((currentNode != null) && (currentNode.NodeType != NodeType.Run));
        }

        // Split the last run that contains the match if there is any text left.
        if ((currentNode != null) && (remainingLength > 0))
        {
            SplitRun((Run)currentNode, remainingLength);
            runs.Add(currentNode);
        }

        // Create Document Builder and insert document
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(e.MatchNode.Document as Document);
        builder.MoveTo((Run)runs[runs.Count - 1]);

        Document doc = new Document(path);
        builder.InsertDocument(doc, ImportFormatMode.KeepSourceFormatting);

        // Now remove all runs in the sequence.
        foreach (Run run in runs)
            run.Remove();

        // Signal to the replace engine to do nothing because we have already done all what we wanted.
        return ReplaceAction.Skip;
    }

    private static Run SplitRun(Run run, int position)
    {
        Run afterRun = (Run)run.Clone(true);
        afterRun.Text = run.Text.Substring(position);
        run.Text = run.Text.Substring(0, position);
        run.ParentNode.InsertAfter(afterRun, run);
        return afterRun;
    }
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

```
Document docList=new Document("");//your file

docList.appendDocument(tempDoc, ImportFormatMode.KEEP_SOURCE_FORMATTING);
```

Comment: Older versions of Aspose don't have appendDocument methods as the new ones. but thanks.

Comment: We always encourage our customers to use the latest version of Aspose.Words as it contains newly introduced features, enhancements and fixes to the issues that were reported earlier. Also, the latest version (15.8.0) does include Document.AppendDocument method.